# JS divs with equal coordinates have different offset

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to display divs with some information after a client clicks on a small dot-like div (7x7px black background) pointing to a place on a map. It works but the distance between the dot-like div and the information div is different in every dot-information couple.

Here is the HTML/JS script. Please, don't mind that all the JavaScript and CSS are in the same file, it is done for the sake of simplicity and will be changed lately.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf8" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="pointer_div" 
onclick="getClickPosition(event)" 
style="position:absolute; top:1px; left:1px; border: 1px solid black;
   background-repeat: no-repeat; width: 1146px; height: 714px;" >

  <div id="sofia"
  onclick="showForecast('Sofia_381_178')"
  style="position:relative; top: 381px; left: 178px;
  background:black; width: 7px; height: 7px;" ></div>

  <div id="plovdiv"
  onclick="showForecast('Plovdiv_512_435')"
  style="position:relative; top: 512px; left: 435px;
  background:black; width: 7px; height: 7px;" ></div>

  <div id="ruse"
  onclick="showForecast('Ruse_77_662')"
  style="position:relative; top: 77px; left: 662px;
  background:black; width: 7px; height: 7px;" ></div>

  <div id="result_data" 
  style="visibility:hidden; width:300px; height:100px; 
         border: 1px solid black; background:white;"/></div>
</div>

<script language="JavaScript">

function showForecast (strr) {
var splits = strr.split('_');
var xcoord = splits[2];
var ycoord = splits[1];

  if (xcoord>810) xcoord= xcoord-300;
  if (ycoord>610) ycoord= ycoord-100;

var resultDiv= document.getElementById("result_data");
resultDiv.style.visibility="visible";
resultDiv.style.position = "relative";
resultDiv.style.left = xcoord;
resultDiv.style.top = ycoord;
resultDiv.innerHTML = 'Forecast for: ' + splits[0];
};

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So, when I click on div "plovdiv", info div appears some 30px below the dot-div, but when I click "ruse" the info div shows right below the dot. I checked both in Firefox and SeaMonkey browsers and they behave identically.

I tried to put the script in jsfiddle but it was showing all the info divs at the top left of the page and I couldn't fix that. Here it is anyway, if anyone is interested [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wkz6dj04/4/).

The coordinates for the info divs are passed to the JS function in a string, and they are the same as those of the dot divs (one of the reasons I kept the css in the html file). I hope someone with better understanding of JS will be able to explain that.

Comment: When I view it, all of them show in the top-left.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose I was missing the "px" after the coordinates in JS. Just look at the answer below where that is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are using `position:relative` on your divs, which moves them from the position they would be in by default. So (because divs are a block element) ruse would be under plovdiv which would be under sofia, then they are moved by the `top` and `left` values. Make them all `position: absolute` and they'll behave uniformly.

Here's your code working in jsfiddle(I added px units to your js): https://jsfiddle.net/wkz6dj04/5/

```
#sofia {
  position: absolute;
  top: 381px;
  left: 178px;
  background: black;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
}

#plovdiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 512px;
  left: 435px;
  background: black;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
}

#ruse {
  position: absolute;
  top: 77px;
  left: 662px;
  background: black;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
}
```

Here's the code working with the above modifications: https://jsfiddle.net/wkz6dj04/6/

If you want the gap back in, I suggest using `margin-top` on your `#result_data` like in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wkz6dj04/7/

Comment: thanks a lot. I really forgot about the "relative" positioning and how it actually works.